# Produce an excel ouput file step for each case in a Switch/Case step in Pentaho

Tags: excel, integration, pentaho, etl, pentaho-spoon

I have a Text file input step, which reads from several files under the same directory, and produce a huge dataset. I need to produce an excel file output for each case in a ***Switch / Case*** statement and give **each** excel file a name, based on the value of some field in the dataset.
 Is this possible with Spoon ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What have you tried? What was the result.

Comment: I played around with the Swith Case step interface but I didn't notice there was any option for producing a step for each  case, Just FYI I'm completely new in the world of ETL :)

Comment: You need to make the different steps, and then create the Excel files there.

Comment: Not so good for me, there are lot of different cases :) if I do like you suggest, I'd rather script things myself , why would I choose to use an ETL ?! To get routines automated of course ..

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe if you describe your problem with sample input and output someone can help you with a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want many cases from a SwitchCase, I'm not sure why you would use a SwitchCase for a datastream that would result in many cases.

Having said that:

1. add one "Add constants" step before the SwitchCase.
2. For each Case coming out of the SwitchCase, add a "Set field value" step that assigns the value of your "some field in the dataset" to the value
   of the Constant you created in #1.  If you have 5 streams (with 1
   stream for each case), you will have 5 of these out of the
   SwitchCase
3. Following each "Set field value" step (created in #2),
   you'll have a step to save your file to Excel, and use the value of
   the field (that you set in #2) as the Filename.

I'm sure there are better ways to do this (assuming that SwitchCase is the right approach for you to start with), but it's how I would do it (not knowing java, regex, or any other language).